# Can I cast into struct?

Tags: c, casting

**EDIT** - question is answered in comments.

I've been browsing `cppreference.com` and found a certain piece of code and ended up with the following after a little elaboration on it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct T { double a[4] };

struct T f(void) { return (struct T){3.15}; }    //Is that casting into struct T?? 
                                                 //But isn't casting into non-scalar not possible?

int main (void)
{
    double d = *f().a;                           //What?
    printf("%f\n", d);
}
```

The question that relates to the topic is on the line with the first comment. I do kinda understand what's happening (i guess) but the syntax is not clear for me - could someone elaborate on it please?

Additional question (if possible to have two) is about the line with the second comment - so, i can use a return value of a function just as is in an expression, like in a given example?

Comment: It's not a cast, it's a compound literal. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal

Comment: They use similar syntax.

Comment: And of course you can use the return value of a function in an expression. Haven't you ever written something like `f()+1`?

Comment: And if you couldn't use return values in expressions, how would you use them? Assignments are expressions in C.

Comment: I wish I could find a canonical dup for questions about compound literal syntax. All I can find are questions about more advanced issues regsarding them.

Comment: @Barmar as for compound literals - haven't used them before, thanks! As for a function example - sure, but the syntax was a bit surprising, now after your comment i see the logic. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Barmar - i've just thought a bit on my last question and, well, it doesn't make sense, sorry, i delete it.

Comment: But that `*` in `*f().a` _is_ confusing and totally superfluous.

Comment: @koder - ahah, probably should participate in the international obfuscated C code contest)